# YAML translations

Tags: translation, yaml

I want to do something like this:

```
character:
    create: Nowa postać
    inventory: Ekwipunek
    reset: Reset postaci
    select: Wybór postaci
    shop: Bazar
    skills: Umiejętności
character: Postać
```

But it causes, that only last translation works.

When I do something like this:

```
character: Postać
character:
    create: Nowa postać
    inventory: Ekwipunek
    reset: Reset postaci
    select: Wybór postaci
    shop: Bazar
    skills: Umiejętności
```

Only the first translation doesn't work.

I can do:

```
character:
    "":Postać
    create: Nowa postać
    inventory: Ekwipunek
    reset: Reset postaci
    select: Wybór postaci
    shop: Bazar
    skills: Umiejętności
```

But it is not a good solution to me ("." at the end of translation key).

Comment: Not that I understand what ‘translation’ is supposed to mean in this context, but you're reusing a key (`character`) in an associative array, which means you can't have both values.

Comment: Yep, I know. I only want to know, if a other solution exists than using a `"":Postać`/a  'character.create: ...` `character.select: ...` character: ...` Arrays are very pretty and easy to read

Comment: Using lists in translations IMO is not a good idea :P So I'm forced to use solution with `"":Postać`

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do, so knock yourself out.

Comment: I want to create a YML file to translating language on the site^^ Using arrays is the best idea to do this, but the problem described by me is a bit annoying xD

Comment: But rather better way to do this doesn't exist, than using `"":translated_text`

Answer (score 0):

If would just make the translation of `character` the toplevel key value pair, with its character related translations to be a mapping that is the value for the translation of character:

```
character: 
    Postać:
        create: Nowa postać
        inventory: Ekwipunek
        reset: Reset postaci
        select: Wybór postaci
        shop: Bazar
        skills: Umiejętności
```

That way it is clear that `Umiejętności` relates to character::skills and not some other skills